# Вычислить название года в восточном календаре

Tags: java, switch

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить данную задачу в Java. Не совсем понятно, как её реализовать через switch.

Задача:

> В восточном календаре принят 60-летний цикл, состоящий из 12-летних подциклов, обозначаемых названиями цвета: зеленый, красный, желтый, белый и голубой. В каждом подцикле годы носят названия животных: крысы, коровы, тигра, зайца, дракона, змеи, лошади, овцы, обезьяны, курицы, собаки и свиньи. По номеру года определить его название, если 1984 год — начало цикла: «год зеленой крысы».

Примеры:

```
Введите год: 2012
Ответ: дракон, голубой 

Введите год: 1956
Ответ: обезьяна, красный
```

Comment: не нужен здесь switch... Лучше массив значений.

Comment: @pavel безусловно лучше массив, но по заданию должен быть именно switch (( к сожалению

Comment: На первом шаге на основе введенного года определяете его место от начала 60 летнего цикла(например 5 год из 60). На втором шаге в свиче выбрать период, в который этот год попадает. И не нужен никакой массив

Answer (score 2):

Если вам обязательно через switch то как-то так:

```
int year = 2016;
int deltaYear = year % 60; //откинем все прошедшие циклы
int colorYear = deltaYear % 12; // какой сейчас цвет

String color;
switch(colorYear){
    //кейсы по цветам
    // color = "цвет";
}

int animalYear = deltaYear / 12; // какое сейчас животное

String animal;
switch(animalYear ){
    //кейсы по животным
    // animal = "животное";
}

return animal + ", " + color;
```

Но я согласен, что проще завести массивы с цветом и животным и просто вытащить по индексу.

Answer (score 2):

**Шаг 1:** На основе года определяете его позицию в 60 летнем цикле.

Например введен 1998 год, его позиция будет 14.

**Шаг 2:** Определяете, в каком интервале он находится

Примерно

```
     Если меньше 12 то зеленый
     Если меньше 24 то красный
     Если меньше 36 то желтый
     ...
```

Для примера выше он будет красным.

**Шаг 3:** Берете остаток от деления на 12, и получаете позицию года в 12 летнем  цикле
       Примерно:

```
   Если 1 то крыса
   Если 2 то корова
   Если 3 то тигр
   ...
```

**PS**
Сознательно не писал код, так как это задача учебная, и хотя бы код вы должны написать сами